# Change ajax url from value listbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, listbox

How can I change the AJAX URL so it gets its value from the `select`?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tester</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#button").click(function() {
                    $("#loading").show();
                    var artikel = $("#text").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<path>/test1.php", // <-- change url from listbox value test1.php / test2.php / test3.php
                        data: "text=" + artikel,
                        success: function(msg) {
                            $("#result").show();
                            $("#result").html(msg);
                            $("#loading").hide();
                        }
                    });
                });

                $("#reset").click(function() {
                    $("#result").html("");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
            <form>
                <select id="listbox">
                    <option value="test1.php">Test 1</option>// send value to ajax url
                    <option value="test2.php">Test 2</option>// send value to ajax url
                    <option value="test3.php">Test 3</option>// send value to ajax url</select>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <textarea placeholder="Write your text here..." class="custom" rows="10" cols="80" name="isi" id="text"></textarea>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="button" value="Go" class="btn-rewriter btn-rewriter-success" id="button">
                <input type=reset id="reset" class="btn-clear btn-clear-success" value="Clear">
            </form>
            <img src="img/loading.gif" style="display:none" id="loading">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <div id="result" style="display:none;"></div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the currently selected value of the `select` using `val()` and append it to the URL string:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#loading").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<path>/" + $('#listbox').val(), // < appended here
        data: { 
            text: $("#text").val()
        },
        success: function(msg){
            $("#result").html(msg).show();
            $("#loading").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Also note that I changed the `data` property to an object so that jQuery will encode it for you, if required.